# Data motion in Cassandra/HDFS and Spark

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, apache-spark, hdfs, distributed-computing

When designing a distributed storage and analytics architecture, is it a common usage pattern to run an analytics engine on the same machine as the data nodes? **Specifically, would it make sense to run Spark/Storm directly on Cassandra/HDFS nodes?**

I know that MapReduce on HDFS has this sort of usage pattern since [according to Hortonworks](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.1.3/bk_using-apache-hadoop/content/yarn_overview.html), YARN minimizes data motion. I have no idea whether this is the case with these other systems though. I would imagine it is since they seem to be so pluggable with each other, but I can't seem to find any information about this online.

I'm sort of a newbie on this topic, so any resources or answers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it makes sense to run Spark on Cassandra nodes to minimize data movement between machines.

When you create an RDD from a Cassandra table, the RDD partitions will be created from the token ranges that are local to each machine.

Here's a link to a talk on this subject for the Spark Cassandra connector:

[Cassandra and Spark: Optimizing for Data Locality](https://spark-summit.org/2015/events/cassandra-and-spark-optimizing-for-data-locality/)

As it says in the summary: "There are only three things that are important in doing analytics on a distributed database: Locality, locality and locality."